New email notifications are stealing focus from Thunderbird window since upgrade 22.04->24.04
This is the problem: Every time I am getting a new email and the notification from Thunderbird pops up, the notification will grab the focus from Thunderbird if I'm using Thunderbird at that moment. When the notification has faded away, focus is going back to Thunderbird.
The notifications are not stealing focus from other windows/apps.
Because so much has changed from 22.04 to 24.04, I don't know which of the changes might cause this. With 22.04 Thunderbird was installed from repository, in 24.04 it is a snap install, for a start, so maybe this is a snap problem?
Whether "Use the system notification" is checked or not in Thunderbird General Settings, section Incoming Mail, does not make a difference. It actually always uses its own notifications, the type with white background, Thunderbird logo on the left, appearing in the bottom right corner of the screen (whereas system notifications appear in the top right corner and look very different).
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, Unity 7.7, Thunderbird 128.3.1esr (64-bit)

Possible bug in Thunderbird. See one report at Mozilla: https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/discussions/regression-thunderbird-incoming-mail-alert-now-steals/m-p/46995
